# Get Comment Author Meta in Comment.php

Tags: wordpress

I built my own `comments.php` on my project. I want to get the comment author custom meta data in `custom_comments.php`.

I search every page on Google, but have not found any answers.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
$args = array (
'post_id' => $post_id
);
$comments = get_comments( $args );
if ( !empty( $comments ) ) :
foreach( $comments as $comment ) :
?>
    <li>
    <?php echo get_the_author_meta('mo_ldap_local_custom_attribute_title', $user->ID); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, first get user name:

```
<?php $author = get_comment_author( $comment_ID ); ?>
```

From codex:

```
$user = get_user_by('login',$author);
if($user){
   echo $user->ID;
   $userID = $user->ID;
}
```

and then You can get author info by:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_meta

```
<?php the_author_meta( $field, $userID ); ?>
```